# Can I use phonegap to call methods on my custom Objective C class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova

Is phonegap just a wrapper for Device APIs or can I use it as a bridge to my own ObjC classes and methods? I don't see anything in the DOCs that says I can call my own code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhoneGap gives you the options to write plugins that you can use as a bridge betweeen your .js and your custom ObjC listener class. The negative is that you'll have to write a native version of your class for each mobile platform. However, I was able to get my ObjC plugin running in a matter of minutes after reading the tutorial.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS